# MVEL vs reflection. What is generally faster regarding object member access?

Tags: java, reflection, mvel

What is generally faster regarding object member access?
1. Execute compiled mvel expression
2. Execute cached reflection method

Answer (score 0):

| Records | From Json | From Dto | To Dto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **With Getter/Setter** | 7,335,792.22 | 1,130,815.56 | 1,239,896.67 |
| 10 | 49,263.33 | 16,240.00 | 13,446.67 |
| 1000 | 392,000.00 | 93,250.00 | 84,123.33 |
| 100000 | 21,566,113.33 | 3,282,956.67 | 3,622,120.00 |
| **With Reflection** | 26,754,304.44 | 15,027,837.78 | 15,356,792.22 |
| 10 | 136,566.67 | 63,640.00 | 52,193.33 |
| 1000 | 1,294,553.33 | 618,830.00 | 542,986.67 |
| 100000 | 78,831,793.33 | 44,401,043.33 | 45,475,196.67 |
| **With Mvel** | 36,520,687.78 | 50,511,424.44 | 50,790,170.00 |
| 10 | 5,707,033.33 | 515,293.33 | 463,266.67 |
| 1000 | 1,535,563.33 | 1,850,083.33 | 1,838,030.00 |
| 100000 | 102,319,466.67 | 149,168,896.67 | 150,069,213.33 |

The below image shows stats corresponding to a small test code that measures the performance of three different approaches to access members of a POJO.

1. With Getter/Setters
2. With Reflection
3. With Mvel compiled expression

[image]

For each approach, there were three record sets viz., 10 records, 1000 records and 100,000 records. Each record set was executed 30 times and relevant measurement is taken as average in nanoseconds.

Comment: Mind sharing the test code? Do you use JMH?

Comment: will setup a github repo to share relevant code but in general above stats answer your question